# Can the most recent common ancestor in git be ambiguous?

Tags: git, ambiguity, ancestor

Since revisions can have multiple parents (merges) and multiple children, can't the "most recent common ancestor" be ambiguous?

For example:

```
A---B--C--D                                                                                                                                               
 \   \   /
  \   E /
   \ / /
    F-G
```

The most recent common ancestor for E and D might be B or F.

I tried replicating this in git and I think it gave B as the common ancestor. Is there a rationale here to pick B over F? Perhaps resorting to timestamps? Or is it simply the first common ancestor discovered by the algorithm, which would be an arbitrary implementation detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not just possible, it's mentioned in the [documentation for `git merge-base`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html):

> *git merge-base* finds best common ancestor(s) between two commits to use in a three-way merge. One common ancestor is better than another common ancestor if the latter is an ancestor of the former. A common ancestor that does not have any better common ancestor is a *best common ancestor,* i.e. a merge base. **Note that there can be more than one merge base for a pair of commits.**

[emphasis mine—I think the emphasized sentence should include the word "best", really], and:

> ... Neither one is better than the other (both are *best* merge bases). When the `--all` option is not given, it is unspecified which best one is output.

(which means, as you suggested, it's an implementation detail).